# Search technique in Mysql using only sql not pl/sql

Tags: string, search

Here i want to search from one table's column to another table's column.
so if  the string is "Introduction To Php"  so this string will compare to another table all data for particular column but the new things is order of words may be different in table.
i.e : it can be like "Php introduction to" , "to indtroduction php" and so on... means combination of different words and there place in the string should be compare with

If you have any idea related this , please answer for this question.
Thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in full-text search functions in MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html